# Ajax success callback not getting called on 200 network response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML page which loads jquery 3.3.1 and external script file script.js. I am running a simple node [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) which serves the static page. data.json in also in at same folder of HTML file. But when below ajax call is done, I can see request is successful in network call but, success call back of ajax call is never getting called. why?[image]

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 

    // Get data from json file        
   $.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);        
    },
   error: function (xhr) { 
    alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText); 
   }
});
    
    
    
    
});
```

```html
    <html>
<head>
    <title>BW Chart</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I can see it's calling error function but why even on status 200 its calling error function

[image]

**data.json**

```
[{name:"Object 1",
  hot:12,
  warm:5,
  cold:56,
  pHot:85,
  pWarm:52,
  pCold:25
 },{name:"Object 2",
  hot:14,
  warm:55,
  cold:23,
  pHot:89,
  pWarm:14,
  pCold:56
 },{name:"Object 3",
  hot:56,
  warm:45,
  cold:26,
  pHot:85,
  pWarm:41,
  pCold:36
 },{name:"Object 4",
  hot:15,
  warm:56,
  cold:47,
  pHot:25,
  pWarm:28,
  pCold:19
 },{name:"Object 5",
  hot:18,
  warm:52,
  cold:12,
  pHot:46,
  pWarm:52,
  pCold:73
 }]
```

Comment: Add an error call back as well to make sure there are no errors

Comment: Check browser console for any errors

Comment: If you're using Chrome, try to press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Del` to clear `Caches images and files`. Then, refresing the page and try again. Chrome loves to troll dev like that  Also, your configuration missed a `type: 'GET'` property.

Comment: please paste your `data.json`. your `script.js` is correct.

Comment: I suppose you need to also have a callback for `error` and check for error.

Comment: I have updated the question with error callback and JSON I am calling

Comment: Your JSON is not [valid](https://jsonlint.com/), You can [fix](http://www.fixjson.com/) it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `script.js` looks fine, no errors there. But your `success` method, of jQuery Ajax call, will fail to execute if browser fails to parse JSON. Make sure your `data.json` is a valid JSON and does not contain any syntax errors...
For example in JSON file, all property names should be double quoted.

Comment: all property names should be double quoted , that was the issue